# Modify each element in a list

Tags: python, list

I thought this question was easy enough but couldn't find an answer.
I have a list of tuples of length 2.
I want to get a list of tuples of length 3 in which the third element is the result of some operation over the other two.
Example:

```
for val_1, val_2 in list_of_tuples
    #...
    #some multi line operation
    #...
    val_3 = result
    replace (val_1, val_2) by (val_1, val_2, val_3) in list
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't (shouldn't) modify a list while looping over it with `for`.  What are you really trying to do?  Do you want to make a new list with the required contents, or make a copy at the beginning and loop over that instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like

```
for index, (val_1, val_2) in enumerate(list_of_tuples):
    # do stuff
    val_3 = # something
    list_of_tuples[index] = (val_1, val_2, val_3)
```

Comment: @Kevin In this case they are neither inserting nor removing elements, so this will not cause a problem. If they were appending or popping that would be a different story. The statement *"No, don't modify things you are iterating over"* is true in some cases, this is not one of them.

Comment: Does the job for me. I prefer if over defining a function an use list comprehension as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 10):

Use a list comprehension.

```
>>> list_of_tups = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
>>> [(i,j,i+j) for i,j in list_of_tups]
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 5), (3, 4, 7)]
```

Now re-assign it back

```
>>> list_of_tups = [(i,j,i+j) for i,j in list_of_tups]
```

Do not modify lists while iterating as it can have some bad effects.

Comment: if you truly want to replace it, do `list_of_tups[:] = ...`

Comment: @acushner reassigning it here will do the job here :-)

Comment: It does not help. I can't squeeze a multiline operation in a list comprehension. In your example the operation is as easy as it can get: i+j.

Comment: yeah, i was just answering the user's specific question. didn't want to make the assumption that it was ok, but based on his experience, it probably is.

Comment: @José You can of-course use a list comprehension to do a multiline operation. Just put in a function and then call it in the list comprehension.

Comment: @José [acushner's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32769274/4099593) below explains my above comment clearly

Answer (score 5):

for a multiline operation, it's easy.

```
def f(i, j):
    # math here
    # more math here
    return new_result
```

and then

```
result = [(i, j, f(i, j)) for i, j in tuples]
```

Comment: I was writing a nice math function. when I saw this answer. Now I stopped.  :-)